# How to call "equivalent-looking" vertices in graph..?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition

[image]

In the above figure, the vertices expressed as blue dots are "equivalent-looking." Although my expression is somewhat ambiguous, I believe one can simply answer it. How can we call such vertices? What is the relation between blue vertices? How can I properly express the relation between the green vertices graph-theoretically? As general as possible...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "equivalent-looking", but the blue vertices form an independent vertex set and the green ones form another one. So maybe it suffices to say that the blue dots form an independent vertex set.

Answer (score 4):

It seems likely that you are looking for the property v is equivalent to w if their is a graph automorphism f such that f(v)=w. A graph automorphism being a bijection of vertices preserving edge relations. i.e. (v,w) is an edge if and only if (f(v),f(w)) is an edge. A graph would be vertex transitive if all vertices were equivalent in this way. This seems to capture the idea of a graph "looking the same" whether viewed from the vertex v or the vertex w.

Comment: Even if seemingly some vertives of a graph is "equivalent-looking", it may not be vertex-transitive. cf.) en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze%27s_graph